# Commercial Server Migration Service WHM/Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

Does anyone know of any reputable online service that can do WHM/Cpanel to WHM/Cpanel migrations from one host to another. Currently the new host I am using does not support transfer feature with WHM.

I cannot do a backup and upload via FTP since the data amounts to about 25GB and I have a 1Mbps connection. That would take ages to download and then upload.

Kindly help

Comment: We are certified Cpanel server management organization. We can get the migration done for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a high speed VPS service from DigitalOcean and set up an Ubuntu Virtual Machine. From there, did a backup of my cpanel accounts and downloaded them onto the VM. Uploaded the files to my new host. It took me less than 4 hours to transfer 25GB!!

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel/WHM does provides whm to whm migration, which you can use. as you have mention you have whm to whm migration whichmeans you should be owning the VPS or dedicated. Most of the companies now a days offers Free data migration services which you can use.

This will not only save your time but money too as creating the VPS just to download and upload the data on new server is not affordable.

You can connect WHM to WHM backup transfer using backup utility at whm as shown below :

```
Home »
Transfers »
Copy an Account From Another Server With an Account Password
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use  whm panel transfer tool option  because it will reduce time,bandwidth usage.

**Follow the below steps**

1.Login into new server  WHM panel

2.open a transfer tool option

3. **Transfer tool :**

**Remote server ip address**:Existing server ip

**Remote SSH port**:Existing server SSH  port no

**Authentication Login:**

Select Root option (default)

**Authentication method**

**Password**:Existing server password

4.Click Fetch Account List

5.After existing server account list and package list will be displayed

6.Select account which you want to migrate and complete the process.